# Copy into cost budget from new screen

Tags: acumatica

I have created a new form tab screen(Project Sub Tasks) which consists of two tabs, Bill of Quantities and Sub Contractor quotes.

What I would like to achieve is, when I have added a new record to one of the tabs, to write it to the project’s cost budget it’s associated with.

I have tried the following code:

```
// 1. Create an instance of the BLC (graph)
    ProjectEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ProjectEntry>();

    protected void _(Events.FieldUpdated<PMBillOfQuantity, PMBillOfQuantity.amount> e)
    {

        var row = (PMBillOfQuantity)e.Row;

        // 2. Create an instance of the DAC, set key field values (besides the ones whose values are generated by the system),
        //    and insert the record into the cache
        PMCostBudget CB = new PMCostBudget();
        CB.AccountGroupID = 35;
        CB = graph.CostBudget.Insert(CB);

        // 3. Set non-key field values and update the record in the cache
        CB.Amount = row.Amount;
        CB.Description = row.Description;

        CB = graph.CostBudget.Update(CB);
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the graph primary data view (Project) current object is initialized with the target project value and call the graph save action to persist the modification.

```
string projectId = "INTERNAL21";
ProjectEntry projectEntry = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ProjectEntry>();
projectEntry.Project.Current = PXSelect<PMProject, Where<PMProject.contractCD, Equal<Required<PMProject.contractCD>>>>.Select(Base, projectId);

[...]

projectEntry.Save.Press();
```